# 'ConditionSet' object is not iterable for a in A

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to find the maximum of the function below, but if I run my script I get the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ekremkemalucuncu/Desktop/Projects/Astro_HW3/astro.py", line 48, in <module>
    print(maximum(dev, v))
  File "/Users/ekremkemalucuncu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sympy/calculus/util.py", line 797, in maximum
    return function_range(f, symbol, domain).sup
  File "/Users/ekremkemalucuncu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sympy/calculus/util.py", line 204, in function_range
    for critical_point in critical_points:
  File "/Users/ekremkemalucuncu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sympy/sets/sets.py", line 1619, in __iter__
    for a in A:
TypeError: 'ConditionSet' object is not iterable
```

My code is:

```
from sympy import *


h=6.62*10**(-34)
c=3*10**8
kb=1.38*10**(-23)
v,T = symbols('v T',positive=True)
f = (2*h*v**3)/((c**2)*(exp((h*v)/(kb*T))-1))


#Calculating Derivative
derivative_f = f.diff(v)
dev=simplify(derivative_f)
print(maximum(dev, v))
```

Comment: Check the type of `dev` against what `sympy.maximum` expects.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of SymPy gives a different output: NotImplementedError. Note carefully that by default the domain over which `maximum` searches is all real numbers. If you plot your function you can see that its actual maximum is as `-oo`. You should specify `Interval(0, oo)` as the domain (not that it helps in this case).

The `maximum` function fails here because of the symbol `T`. If you aren't going to give values for all symbols (including `T`) besides the unknown `v` that you want to solve for then it's better just to make everything be a symbol:

```
In [49]: from sympy import *
    ...: 
    ...: h, c, kb = symbols('h, c, kb', positive=True)
    ...: v,T = symbols('v T',positive=True)
    ...: f = (2*h*v**3)/((c**2)*(exp((h*v)/(kb*T))-1))
    ...: 
    ...: derivative_f = f.diff(v)
    ...: [sol] = solve(derivative_f, v)

In [50]: sol
Out[50]: 
     ⎛ ⎛    -3⎞    ⎞
T⋅kb⋅⎝W⎝-3⋅ℯ  ⎠ + 3⎠
────────────────────
         h
```

The answer here is given in terms of the Lambert W function but you can just evalf the numeric part of this expression to see that it's a plain number:

```
In [51]: sol.evalf()
Out[51]: 
2.82143937212208⋅T⋅kb
─────────────────────
          h
```